# Suddenly spongy/creaky floorboard patch. What's going on?

Tags: flooring

We've owned this house for about 2.5 years. All hardwood floors upstairs. We put a new bedroom set (considerably larger and heavier than before) in one upstairs room a couple of months ago.

In the past week, I've noticed a patch about 2'x2' that suddenly creaks and sinks slightly when you step on it. This is definitely a new thing.

The room is close to the upstairs bathroom, but none of the pipes really run near it. We have a pull-up bar in a door frame below that area, but it's been there for a year or so.

The patch is not particularly near the exterior walls or structural walls.

I am mystified. What could cause such a sudden change?

Comment: Do you have photos of the area? Can you visualize what support structure is immediately below the affected area? How much movement are you indicating. A "soft" spot or creak can be felt at as little movement at 1/64th of an inch.

Comment: What kind of hardwood floor?  Floating?   Thickness?  Underlayment?

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious are dry rot, termites, and moisture damage. It could be a very slow leak because even if the pipe is further away--water often goes mysteries ways.

Or maybe as simple as a fastener settling.

I would just keep an eye on it and see what happens next.